# GNU Privacy Guard(GPG) in Shell/bash

Tags: shell, gnupg

I was trying to do do some more shell scripting in the last few days.

where I am trying to calculate the value of a function.
To start with I get an

```
echo "blah"
read blub

md5=`md5sum $blub | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
echo $md5

echo "secretkey"
read $SK
```

For example, If get the values like that.
Is it possible at-all to do a calculation with`GPG` like this

`GPG(VALUE1,VALUE2)` in my case it is `GPG(md5,sk)`

Later on I would like to take a modular function over that value. Which is possible via the shell script.

If its possible , May I ask how is it possible to do in GPG. or is there any other better public generating algorithm that can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to GPG-encode the MD5 with GPG? Using `secretkey` as the password?

Comment: @MichałGórny : I encrypt the file using GPG like this `gpg --symmetric --no-use-agent "$blub"`. Now, I try to fetch the secret key and then make a GPG encoding of the (MD5 and secretkey) together for my furthur computations.

Is it possible to do a GPG encoding of (MD5 and secretkey). Or any kind of computation of the secretkey and the md5, Which you think is feasible.

Comment: What do you mean by 'GPG encoding'? What are you trying to achieve in the script? Please talk about the final goal, maybe then I'll understand your wording.

Comment: @MichałGórny: I am sorry about that.

This is what I am trying to achieve :

Let us assume to be a random value between 2 and 100
for every file (t) , I try to generate a secret key and the md5 sum 
Then try to do this. for `t=MOD(GPG(md5,secretkey),d-2)`

This way, I can ensure that each file a different value T. Which I would use

Comment: You still didn't explain what the `GPG(value1,value2)` would have to actually do. Best with an example.

Comment: GPG(VALUE1,VALUE2) Will have to generate a integer/floating point value.

Comment: Some kind of hash? I'm afraid either you have serious problems expressing yourself clearly, or I am missing something very obvious which would make the problem actually self-explanatory.

Comment: Let me try it one last time.

1. The value(INTEGER/FLOATING VALUE) that I fetch via `GPG(VALUE1,VALUE2)` will be used to take a modular function like this `t=mod(GPG(VALUE1,VALUE2),d-2)`. That way I get a different value for `t` everytime , if the file and private key differ

Comment: But to get any value, the function needs to generate it somehow. And you still didn't explain what the function does with the input to generate the output you expect.

Comment: I totally understand the problem now, 

I thought that the GPG could actually compute a value with the given parameters directly and generate a value. 

What do you suggest me to do? What is the best way to compute? :)

Thanks a ton!

Comment: GPG is just a program to encrypt or sign files. It can also generate checksums AKA digests AKA hashes. My only guess is that you are trying to get the latter, i.e. a unique numeric value for the md5+sk pair. So, that would be basically a MD5 or similar function of that pair. Am I correct or is something completely different?

Comment: True. I would like to fetch a unique numeric value for the md5+sk pair :).

Comment: How do I do that kind of a computation?

Comment: By the way, the `read $sk` was intended as `read sk` probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to obtain a digest (hash, checksum) of the MD5 + secret key pair (much like the MD5 is a digest of the `blub`).

In any case, GPG won't help you here. It's mostly a tool for encryption and signing with PGP. It can do symmetric encryption of files as well but AFAICS it doesn't do stand-alone digests, and certainly doesn't do them in decimal form.

The simplest solution seems to be using one of the common shell checksumming tools which actually have numeric output — for example `cksum`.

Those tools take only a single blob as an argument, so you probably want to simply concatenate the input

I think a working example would be:

```
gpg=$(echo "$md5$sk" | cksum | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Then `gpg` will contain some decimal value, unique for each md5 + secret key pair.